# Как удалить один файл из последнего коммита

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Проблема следующая: Хотел запушить на гитлаб три измененных файла, но случайно закоммитил еще один ненужный файл (пока все локально, в удаленную ветку ничего еще не пушил). Что можно сделать чтобы удалить этот лишний файл из коммита?
Все делал через intellij idea.

Comment: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/undo-last-commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Про то, как сделать это из intellij idea не отвечу, а в консоли задачу можно решить, например, так:

1. git reset --soft HEAD~
2. git reset ФАЙЛ_КОТОРЫЙ_НЕ_ДОЛЖЕН_ПОПАСТЬ_В_КОММИТ
3. git commit -m "метка коммита"

[Почитать](http://7.7%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B%20Git%20-%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%20reset)

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @Jigius
На втором этапе лучше выполнить `git restore --staged` файл , чтобы не потерять внесенные изменения в файл.